# Java + Node modules

Tags: java, node.js, module, npm, angular

I'd like to use Angular2 as client side framework + Java as server side, but how to exactly use Angular2 in Java project? Is there something wrong to init NPM system into Java project and then install there all things like Angular2, Typescript, System.js etc?

I'm asking because I have never used something related directly to NPM system in Java project.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Did you find some best practices for your question since ? I would be curious.

Answer (score 2):

Normally front side and server side projects are maintained separately. You could use a build manager like Maven to manage all this kind of stuff: install npm, download dependencies, run tests...

Comment: I want to have maven to do all this stuff but I want to use angular2 for frontend also so my question was is it a good practice to install npm into webapp directory inside Java project. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I would use the webapp directory to save the angular2 app inside, with npm and all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather create Java Api and angular2 projects separately and call REST api methods from client.

for starting projects I'd use [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/)

Comment: I'd like to use Jersey as RESTful Api framework for java and install npm, node_modules containing Angular2 inside webapp package inside Java project. Like Java_Project/src/main/webapp/ <--- here all frontend staff. So is it a good practice to do something like that? What do you think by making two projects separately? That what I'm writing right now is not about making them separately? Thanks

Comment: Well, sure you can have root folder as a JAVA_PROJECT, where you will have some sub-root folder for anulgar2. DO NOT mix angular project and others, I mean, if you create project by anuglar-cli, than do not add folders for java application inside it. Leave API and Angular2 folders independently, grouped by root folder.